# Question about Mersenne numbers

Tags: number-theory

We don't have any proof for [Mersenne conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_conjectures), but is it true that there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $2^p-1$ is not prime?

Comment: So your asking if there are infinitely -many Mersenne primes?

Comment: @Gary. rathre for infinitely many Mersenne composites

Comment: @Gary: No, if we have finitely - many Mersenne primes then the answer of my question is obvious.

Comment: The question is equivalent to proving that there are infinitely many primes $q$ that are not Mersenne primes such that $\text{ord}_q(2)$ is prime

Comment: This is another conjecture and we don't know if there are infinitely composite mersonne numbers or not, we know for example that if $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ and $2p+1$ is prime then $M_p$ is composite, but we don't know if there are infintely many pair primes $(p,2p+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is known whether infinitely many Mersenne numbers are composite, but it is generally suspected to be so.

Comment: This is my understanding, as well. See, e.g., the Wikipedia piece on Mersenne primes, where it says, "It is also not known whether infinitely many Mersenne numbers with prime exponents are composite, although this would follow from widely believed conjectures about prime numbers...."

Comment: Another Q was whether a Mersenne number could be a Carmichael number. I haven't a clue.